# Google measurement protocol not showing data in analytics report since 31/10/2019

Tags: c#, google-analytics, measurement-protocol

We are using the Measurement Protocol to record our Ecom data to show it inside analytics reports.
We are currently using this nuget package:
https://github.com/ion-sapoval/google-measurement-protocol-dotnet

Everything was working fine until the 31/10/2019 where all our events suddenly disapeared.

We have found no announcement for this protocol to be deprecated.

The only announcement we have around this date is the following and only concerns mobile tracking:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9167112?hl=en

I also opened a thread here :
https://support.google.com/analytics/thread/21155070?hl=en

**EDIT :** Here is the kind of request I'm sending:

```
POST https://www.google-analytics.com/batch HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
Host: www.google-analytics.com
    Content-Length: 325
    Expect: 100-continue
    Connection: Keep-Alive

t=transaction&v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXX-1&ti=756fc5cd-6417-4bc6-85a3-e91b0495a55a&tr=30&tt=5&cu=CHF&cid=15de9bd4-82fe-401a-ae8f-87fb84e39f1a&pr1cm2=DATA1&pr1cm1=DATA2
t=item&v=1&tid=UA-XXXXXXXXX-1&ti=756fc5cd-6417-4bc6-85a3-e91b0495a55a&cid=15de9bd4-82fe-401a-ae8f-87fb84e39f1a&in=MyItemName&ic=MIN&iv=MyItemCategory&ip=30&iq=1
```

I tried to send it to my personnal tracking tag and **it's working**.
So the **library doesn't seem to be implicated** in this problem.

**EDIT 2 :** After further investigations, It seems like our main google analytics dashboard we are using is misconfigured.

**Creating a new dashboard on the same analytics shows all the data from the Measurement protocol.**

On our main dashboard we disabled all filters and all ecom options are enabled (ecom analytics and enhanced ecom analytics) but the data is still not showing up.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: please edit your question and show the call you are sending to the measurement protocol.  Note that is not the official library so you may want to contact the owner of that library. it also hasnt been updated in six years.

Comment: question edited

Comment: If you are sending that code and its working whats the problem? That code doesnt apear to have anyting to do with your third party six year old library i still think you should contact the owners of that library

Comment: The problem is: it's not working for our main google analytics dashboard. See 2nd edit

Answer (score 0):

**We finally have the answer to this problem :**

A **filter** to exclude some ip was **associated with this view**. Our server is connected to the internet with the same ip.

This filter was already existing so we didn't think about it first. But obviously it was not applied to this view before the 30.10.2019 by the owner of the analytics.

As we are not the owner of the analytics account, We were not able to see the **modification history of the account** until today. This confirmed that the filter was the problem.

Thanks for your help.